# GUI not being instanced

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to make a flare gun and I have a pretty good system set up. I have a debounce timer that prevents the client from spamming it and it tries to display a "Reloading!" gui, but fails. I have the script properly set up and there are no errors, and the print statement inside is running, but no GUI is being instanced.

**Local Script:**

```
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.FlareEvent
local debounce = false
local guiparent = game.StarterGui.WeaponGUI.ReloadFrame
player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(toset)
    character = toset
end)
local i = 0
local sound = script.Parent:WaitForChild("flare sound")
local tool = script.Parent
local acceleration = 20
uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        if character:FindFirstChild("Flare Gun") then
            if debounce == false then
                sound:Play()
                event:FireServer()
                debounce = true
                wait(1)
                debounce = false
            else
                print("Reloading!")
                local text = Instance.new("TextLabel")
                text.Text = "Reloading!"
                text.Transparency = 0
                text.Font = Enum.Font.TitilliumWeb
                text.BackgroundTransparency = 1
                text.Position = UDim2.new(50, 1, 50, 1)
                text.Parent = guiparent
                repeat
                    text.Transparency = text.Transparency + 0.1
                    i += 1
                    wait(0.05)
                until i > 10
                i = 0
                text:Destroy()
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

The script fires a remote event if debounce is false, and prints "Reloading!" when debounce is true.
When I check the hierarchy in-game, I can see that nothing is being instanced to "guiparent". I've made sure that "guiparent" is pointing towards a real section of the hierarchy.

I've tried instancing and I expected it to "summon" a text label. What happened was nothing, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StarterGui is only a storage for the GUI, Roblox will internally clone each GUI in StarterGui to the player's PlayerGui (e.g. game > Players > Builderman > PlayerGui)

To solve this, change guiparent to

```lua
local guiparent = player.PlayerGui:WaitForChid("WeaponGUI").ReloadFrame
```